# Jquery positioning relative to an element which can move

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, position

I am using jquery positioning (my, at, of) to display a div as a sort of 'dropdown' to a button. Code below:

```
if ( $('#myDiv').is(':hidden') ) {
    $('#myDiv').show().position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left bottom",
        of: $("#myButton"),
        "offset" : "0 -2px"
    });

} else {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
}
```

The button can move while the dropdown div is visible (e.g. other content getting dynamically added/removed, pushing the button around). The problem is that when this happens, only the button moves and the div stays put, so div is no longer positioned correctly relative to the button.

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2BUZU/

Is there a *nice* way to have the div always follow the button?

I can't seem to find an answer to this problem, though I'm sure I'm not the only one to run into this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: The positioning of the div should be relative

Comment: Example demo posted. Also, Chibuzo, I tried changing position to relative, but I need the dropdown div to appear on top of other content so I don't think that's going to work - unless I misunderstood you?

Comment: I think the best solution would be to position the element relatively to the button using CSS by placing both the div and the button as children of a positioned parent. If that's not an option you'll need to call `position()` every time the button is moved. If you can't know when the button moves then I guess you can `setInterval()` and check for movement/reposition the div every now and then - although that will be pretty performance heavy.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by adding a container `div` and the animate function. Not sure if this is the kind of solution you are after...

See [**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/UpWDC/)

Hope it helps!

**Second suggestion**
Find the `position()` of the `myButton` element and move `myDiv` appropriately.

See [**jsFiddle DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/y5aV2/)

I have a feeling that you can achieve what you need to achieve using the position and animate functions.

Again, I hope this gets you a bit more closer to your solution.

Comment: Thanks neo108. It doesn't work for me exactly; I need something that would work based on the button moving for any number of reasons, e.g. some content elsewhere on the page getting added/removed. But it's a useful example nonetheless!

Comment: I have a feeling that you can achieve what you need to achieve using the position and animate functions. Please see my second suggestion above - Have edited the answer to add it.

Comment: Thanks for the second demo, neo108. But it seems that the div re-positioning is still triggered via the click that adds more content (nice concise code though!).

Answer (score 0):

While I'd like to have the dropdown div always automatically follow its button, it doesn't seem like there's an easy way in my case. I know what will cause the button to move 90% of the time, so when I am triggering this I am re-positioning the div at that point. So that works well enough for now. Thanks for the tips peoples.